# Remote control of a manual transmission

Tags: control-engineering, automotive-engineering, gears

I want to know if it is possible to control the gearbox of a car with a manual transmission, specifically one with the shift stick in the steering wheel column.

[image: steer column]

The idea is using linear actuators or hydraulic cylinders to control the gas / clutch pedals and "some kind of mechanism" to control the shifting stick directly or removing the gear stick and installing the mechanism on the gearbox directly.

**Is this idea feasible or has it been done before? Or do all autonomous cars use automatic or "tiptronik" gearbox?**

*NOTE: I have taken a look at this post before [Remote start on a car with manual transmission](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/5838/remote-start-on-a-car-with-manual-transmission), but did not find a satisfying answer*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you've described is not that far from a computer-controlled automatic transmission. In fact, so-called [semi-automatic transmission](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-automatic_transmission) seems like a quite good match.

Biggest difference is usually the use of a torque converter instead of a clutch. A friction clutch requires a certain amount of "feel" for the car, to know how fast to release it for a smooth start or gear change. A torque converter is more forgiving of timing, which makes it easier to control automatically.

---

And as for retrofitting such a mechanism to an existing car: it surely has been done, for example in remote control cars for movies. But in general there would be little point to do it that way, when automatic and computer controlled gearboxes are available off-the-shelf.

Comment: "A friction clutch requires a certain amount of "feel" for the car" , exactly as i thought . in addition to placing the gear stick/handle in place , sometimes it fights back and you must not push hard , not a simple computer task!